# Do i have to redo my shahada?

Tags: muslim-practices, shahada

I recently reverted to Islam from being agnostic so please help me. I’ve been having waswas in the beginning and I began to ignore that but now I feel like I am myself having doubts and negative feelings about being a Muslim. I feel really bad about this but I’ve been trying to look for reasons why Islam is the true religion, I’ve been researching and thinking of why other religions could be true, had thoughts of leaving Islam, and just bad thoughts and feelings about Islam in general and I don’t want to say what it is. I never acted upon these or spoke of it but I’ve asked some people about it online. I feel bad and I’m worried if i have to redo my shahada or not?

Comment: Note that if you only pray your daily prayers you are redoing your shahada several times a day.

Answer (score 1):

bad thoughts happen for everyone. A thought can never undo our beliefs.
Your situation(in which I was either) is a trick from Shaytaan. He is really upset because of your reversion to Islam so he is annoying you with waswas.
The solution is to **just do your job and ignore him**. The more you ignore him the more he sees he can't annoy you so eventually he leaves you alone.
Ofcourse all of these never means you should stop researching. Allah likes it when someone searches for the truth or wants to strengthen their belief. He will reward handsomely for such actions.